# How to invoke method in another class and return value from it in java?

Tags: java, class, methods

I have created two classes. In the first class, I have tried to make a method in another class to return a value with a command to output value on the console. But I get an error that says there are incompatible types. Here are two classes that I have created and I wanted to make a calculator out of that:
The first class

```
class calc1
{
    public static int num1; //first number variable
    public static int num2; //Second number variable
    public static String op; //Operatior variable
    public static void main(String[] args) //
    {
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        op = args[1];
        calc3.calculate(op); //Calling method from the second class with an arugement.
    }
}
```

this is the second:

```
class calc3
{
    public static int calculate(String ops)
    {
        switch(ops) //I believe that ops stores value from op variable in the first class.
        {
        case "+": 
            {
                int num = calc1.num1 + calc1.num2;
                return (System.out.println(num));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is an error message I get from a compiler:

```
Desktop$ javac calc1.java
./calc3.java:10: error: incompatible types
        return (System.out.println(num));
                                  ^
 required: int
 found:    void
1 error
```

PS. I was wondering if that the process I am doing is called overloading methods?

Comment: change the following 
int num = calc1.num1 + calc1.num2;
return (System.out.println(num));

from



int num = calc1.num1 + calc1.num2;
return num;

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println` returns `void`. 
Your "calculate" method returns `int`.

If you want to both print the number and return it in your method, you should change your code to:

```
System.out.println(num);
return num;
```

PS: you don't seem to be [overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) any method in there.

Comment: Thanx for advice and I have a good book to learn java basics. I am just exploring ways to call methods.

Comment: Hey, I changed the code in the switch statement to what you suggested and for some weird reason the compiler gives me an error. `./calc3.java:14: error: missing return statement
}
^
1 error`

Comment: You need a default statement in your switch, or a return statement outside the switch.

Comment: Elaborating on last comment: your switch statement has only one condition. If the condition is not met, there is no return statement in your method, which triggers the compilation error. The default statement is used in a switch to fall back to a default condition (don't forget to use the break statement). Otherwise, a return statement outside your switch would act as fallback when the only condition you have is not met. In fact, since you only have one condition, I would recommend an if/else statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your following class

```
class calc3
{
public static int calculate(String ops)
{
switch(ops) //I believe that ops stores value from op variable in the first class.
{
case "+": 
    {
        int num = calc1.num1 + calc1.num2;
        return (System.out.println(num));
    }

}
}
}
```

You are returning `System.out.println(num)` while you should be returning just `num`

`calc3.calculate()` is expecting an int as return type.

As you progress and start doing a lot of coding, you might want to use an IDE such as Eclipse or NetBeans to help you better debug your compile errors and runtime errors.

Comment: I am using jEdit for the moment, because I still learn basics of Java coding. I wonder, can IDEs state exactly what the problem is in the code and does it suggest a solution for it as well?

Comment: Why not find out.  Put the same code that contains your compile error in an ide (for ex: Eclipse).  Hover on the error icon and see if that points you in the right direction.  In a professional environment, majority of us use an IDE.  Thankfully java has excellent tooling support.

Comment: Yeah I will give it a go!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand certain basic concepts of java like

`System.out.println(num);` statement just prints and does not return anything.

So your calculate method is not returning anything but void while its return type is int.

You need to return an int value that should also be out side of a conditional statement (of course you can return in a conditional statement as well) but to satisfy compiler there should be at least one out side conditional statement like viz.

only this will not work

`System.out.println(num);`

`return num;`

Make sure you have a return like statement (`return num;`) out side switch block as well.

Comment: I was thinking, I can use conditional statement to calculate and then assign output to a static variable outside calculate method. Then there are two ways for me to return value. It's whether I address the static variable or I can create another method that will take value from the static variable and return it to the calc1 class. I hope my thinking is correct, am I right?

Comment: 1. Its always better to use getter/setter methods rather than accessing a field directly 2. Calculating and assigning value to an outside static variable should be used in rare situation as you must be aware that if you create two objects of class and  call method on these objects they will over rite the static variable because it is only one per class.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few comments :

- In this case the compiler message was pretty clear. As Mena pointed out, `System.Out.Println()` is a function that [returns nothing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) (`void`). However your `calculate` function should return an `int`.
- you need to return a value, as pointed out by others

  ```
  int num = calc1.num1 + calc1.num2;
  return (System.out.println(num));
  ```

could become :

```
    return calc1.num1 + calc1.num2;
```

- Yes, I did ommit the `System.out.println` statement. I think you could use a debugger for that purpose.
- A `switch` statement without a `default` case is bad. In this case, returning a value directly from the switch is acceptable, however the "normal" way of constructing a switch statement uses `break`. See [the oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).
- Class names usually begin with an uppercase letter (`Calc1`, `Calc2`...). This is just a convention.
- There is no overloading in your code. You may want to have a look at overwriting by the way : [overloading vs overwriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837864/java-overloading-vs-overwriting).