# What is the technical term for two functions with the same signature and same behavior, but different names?

Tags: computer-science, terminology, language-design

When we say that one aspect of a program can be changed *completely independently* of another aspect, we say those things are *orthogonal* to one another.

I am looking for pretty much the **opposite** term.  For example, it's a good idea in C++ if the copy-assignment operator has the same calling signature as the copy-constructor, and if they have identical effects (or are close enough not to care).  Thus, one might say or write: "it is good class design in C++ to make the copy-constructor and assignment operator _______ to each other."

[EDIT]  I'm asking for the computer-language concept related to the following statement: "these two functions have separate identities but similar roles, and therefore should have the same argument types, the same return types (if possible), and same (or highly similar) side-effects or behavior."

This question is not about C++, nor about object-orientation.
I am looking for a more general Computer Science or mathematical concept here.

Comment: maybe you are asking about overloading-vs-overriding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837864/java-overloading-vs-overriding

Comment: Thanks for asking!  No, this is explicitly NOT overloading versus overriding; I'm quite familiar with the difference between the two.  You're sort of asking the question in the wrong direction.  I'm asking for the computer-language concept that says: "these two functions have separate identities but similar roles, and therefore should have similar argument types, similar return types, and similar side-effects or behavior.  I'm trying for something like "isomorphic" or "homomorphic" to fill in the blank above, but I'm not sure either term is correct.

Comment: PS: I almost asked this in the "English Language & Usage" forum, but I am really looking for the accepted terminology that would be used when talking about computer language definitions, compilers, and the like.  Would I get better responses here, there, or on the math forum?  Please advise.

Comment: maybe you are asking about polymorphism? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: @mruanova, please read my comments above, then re-read the question.  This is not about polymorphism.  It's not about C++ or object-orientation at all.  It is about language theory and the terminology used within it.  This is why the question carries a "terminology" tag but NOT a "C++" tag.  Please don't be confused or misdirected by my usage of an example statement regarding C++.  I'd prefer not to remove the C++ example from the question (it succinctly states a very real candidate usage of the term).

Comment: I guess the technical terms is Forbinism then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183159/discussion-between-forbin-and-mruanova).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean two functions like this?

f: T -> R 
g: T -> R

For All x in T, f(x) == g(x)

And accepting also same side effects (in math there are no side effects of a function)

g and f are just equivalent functions.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I'm looking for!  However, I don't think we'd call them "equivalent functions" in Computer Science, because they might not be *exactly* equivalent.  @mnesarco, I think I'm looking for a term that means "extreme similarity," or "closely related."   Maybe a term related to the concept of "parallel"?  (Since "orthogonal" is derived from Latin for "at a right angle to.")

Comment: I'm giving the question another day or two to see if anyone can shed more light on the subject.  If that doesn't happen, I'll be upvoting and accepting this.

Comment: Not everything has to have a proper name. Your functions are just closely related functions. I think the case is not common or important enough to deserve a proper name.