# Is it overloading if a class implements muplitple interfaces with similar methods?

Tags: java, interface, overloading

I'm curious to know whether it could be considered as method overloading if a class implements two or more interfaces with **similar** methods. If not then what's the right terminology?

Take an example

```
public interface I1 {
  int method1(String input);
}

public interface I2 {
  void method1(int input);
}

public class C1 implements I1, I2 {
  public int method1(String input){ return 0;}

  public void method1(int input){}
}
```

Comment: The compiler knows which one is being implemented by the signature. For class C1, as long as both methods are implemented, then that is fine. You could equally have both methods defined in a single interface, it would make no difference. So yes method 1 is overloaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java overloading vs overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837864/java-overloading-vs-overriding)

Comment: Typically I have seen / used scenarios wherein a super class / interface had overloaded methods. Then I thought what would be the right terminology if above scenario happens. Based on your inputs I think it is safe to say it is overloading.

Comment: *FYI:* 1) `interface` is spelled in all lowercase. --- 2) The methods in `C1` *must* be declared `public`. --- 3) The methods in `C1` *should* be annotated with `@Override`.

Comment: @Andreas it was just an example to show what I am asking. You can't be serious about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overloading boils down to:

> In Java, two or more methods may have the same name if they differ in parameters (different number of parameters, different types of parameters, or both). These methods are called overloaded methods and this feature is called method overloading.

From [here](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/method-overloading).

So, obviously, your class `C1` does **overload** `method1()`. The fact that it does that in order to **override** the two methods doesn't change that. It doesn't matter to the definition of overloading if overriding happens, too.

Comment: Note that if both interface methods are `default`, and you don't override them in `C1`, the methods are still *overloaded* by `C1`.